# Zend Framework 3 : Unable to resolve service as a factory

Tags: php, zend-framework, model

I already saw many threads about my issue but none of the was able to fix it..

Indeed, I made a factory for my FournitureTable Model and the error returned is :

```
Unable to resolve service "Fourniture\Model\FournitureTable" to a factory; are you certain you provided it during configuration?
```

Here's the main structure of my module:

```
... Fourniture
  /config/module.config.php
  /src/Controller/FournitureController.php
      /Factory/FournitureControllerFactory.php
      /Model
         /Factory/FournitureTableFactory.php
         Fourniture.php
         FournitureTable.php
      Module.php # Which only contains getConfig() method
```

FournitureTable.php

```
<?php 
    namespace Fourniture\Model;

    use RuntimeException;
    use Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGatewayInterface;
    use Zend\Db\Sql\Expression;
    use Zend\Db\Sql\Select;

    class FournitureTable {
        private $tableGateway;
        
        public function __construct(TableGatewayInterface $tableGateway){
            $this->tableGateway = $tableGateway;
        }

        public function fetchAll(){
            return $this->tableGateway->select();
        }

        public function getSupplyByCategId($id){
            
            $select = $this->tableGateway->getSql()->select()
            ->join(['sc' => 'sous_categorie'], 'fournitures.categorie = sc.id', ['nom'],
                Select::JOIN_LEFT)
            ->where(['fournitures.categorie' => (int)$id]);
            
            $result = $this->tableGateway->selectWith($select);
            return $result;
        }
    }
?>
```

FournitureTableFactory.php

```
<?php

namespace Fourniture\Model\Factory;

use Fourniture\Model\Fourniture;
use Fourniture\Model\FournitureTable;

use Interop\Container\ContainerInterface;
use Interop\Container\Exception\ContainerException;

use Zend\Db\ResultSet\ResultSet;
use Zend\Db\Adapter\AdapterInterface;
use Zend\Db\TableGateway\TableGateway;

use Zend\ServiceManager\Exception\ServiceNotCreatedException;
use Zend\ServiceManager\Exception\ServiceNotFoundException;
use Zend\ServiceManager\Factory\FactoryInterface;

class FournitureTableFactory implements FactoryInterface
{
    public function __invoke(ContainerInterface $container, $requestedName, array $options = null)
    {
        $dbAdapter = $container->get(AdapterInterface::class);
        $resultSetPrototype = new ResultSet();
        $resultSetPrototype->setArrayObjectPrototype(new Fourniture());
        $tableGateway = new TableGateway('fournitures', $dbAdapter, null, $resultSetPrototype);

        return new FournitureTable($tableGateway);
    }
}
```

module.config.php

```
<?php
//@NOTE : Se référer aux commentaires de /module/Application/config/module.config.php pour le routage, les contrôleurs et les vues

use Fourniture\Model\FournitureTable;
use Fourniture\Controller\FournitureController;
use Fourniture\Factory\FournitureControllerFactory;
use Fourniture\Model\Factory\FournitureTableFactory;
use Zend\Router\Http\Segment;

return [
    'controllers' => [
        'factories' => [
            Fourniture\Controller\FournitureController::class => Fourniture\Factory\FournitureControllerFactory::class,
            Fourniture\Model\FournitureTable::class => Fourniture\Model\Factory\FournitureTableFactory::class,
        ],
    ],
    'view_manager' => [
        'template_path_stack' => [
            'fourniture' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
            __DIR__ . '/../view', 
        ],
    ],
];
?>
```

I'm new on Zend 3 and StackOverflow so sorry if my explanation are a little consfused.

Also sorry if my English is not perfect, I'm French.

Thank's in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declared the factory under the wrong configuration key.

`controllers` configuration is meant, as the name suggests, for... controllers. Only the `ControllerManager` looks inside into that configuration.

The one you are looking for is `service_manager`, as told in the [tutorial](https://docs.zendframework.com/tutorials/getting-started/database-and-models/#using-servicemanager-to-configure-the-table-gateway-and-inject-into-the-albumtable). 
Actually, in the tutorial they retrieve the configuration through the `ConfigProviderInterface` methods, but [here](https://docs.zendframework.com/tutorials/advanced-config/#configuration-mapping-table) you'll find the corresponding array key configuration.

Last two tips:

- since you are declaring all the classes at the beggining of the file (`use ....`), there is no need to use the fully qualified name space inside the array
- try to keep consistence in your structure. You put `FournitureTableFactory` inside the `\Model\Factory` folder, but the `FournitureControllerFactory` inside `Factory` folder. Two factories located in two locations, following two different logics, it doesn't make a lot of sense ;)

Change your `module.config.php` with this:

```php
<?php

use Fourniture\Model\FournitureTable;
use Fourniture\Controller\FournitureController;
use Fourniture\Factory\FournitureControllerFactory;
use Fourniture\Model\Factory\FournitureTableFactory;
use Zend\Router\Http\Segment;

return [
    'controllers' => [
        'factories' => [
            FournitureController::class => FournitureControllerFactory::class
        ],
    ],
    'service_manager' => [
        'factories' => [
            FournitureTable::class => FournitureTableFactory::class
        ]
    ],
    'view_manager' => [
        'template_path_stack' => [
            'fourniture' => __DIR__ . '/../view',
            __DIR__ . '/../view', 
        ],
    ],
];
?>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it indeed worked ! 

I'll keep your advice in mind for the following :-)